# How can we force users to aways enter their passwords when signing in to AAD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a WPF application that allows users to authenticate against an AAD B2C custom policy by calling AcquireTokenInteractive() from MSAL.NET (4.54.1). The sign-in process works, but after signing in the first time, AcquireTokenInteractive() allows users to sign in again just by entering their usernames, without re-entering their passwords. The WPF app runs on computers in an office setting where multiple people have physical access to each machine and usernames are well known to all. Therefore, someone can sign in by typing someone else's username without a password, and this is a security risk.

According to [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/264757/how-to-sign-out-of-azure-adb2c), "There is no default Sign out flow under userflows in AAD B2C". Instead, the thread suggests redirecting the user "to the end_session endpoint that is listed in the OpenID Connect metadata document". But how do we do that from a WPF native app? Is there a method in MSAL.NET that does this? Or, if we send a GET request with a plain .NET HttpClient, how do we identify the user that we want to sign out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We opened a support ticket, and the Microsoft B2C team gave us the solution. When B2C sends a sign in request to the IDP, it needs to include a query string parameter that says "prompt=login". (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) In a B2C custom policy, this is done by 1) defining a ClaimType named "prompt", and 2) setting its value to "login" in the IDP's Technical Profile.

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy ...>
    <BuildingBlocks>
        ...
      <ClaimsSchema>
        <ClaimType Id="aadPrompt">
          <DataType>string</DataType>
          <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
            <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="prompt" />
          </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        </ClaimType
        ...
... 
      <ClaimsProvider>
        ...
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Common-AAD">
            <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
            <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
            <InputClaims>
              <InputClaim 
                 ClaimTypeReferenceId="aadPrompt" 
                 DefaultValue="login"
              />
            ...
```

And voila, Entra ID prompts for the user's password.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redirect the user to the logout endpoint as shown in that thread by opening it in the default browser (usually the same that is used to login).

You can also try reducing the [session lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-azure-ad-b2c-session-behavior) so that the session cookie in the user's browser expires faster than usual and ensure that [Keep me signed in (KMSI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#enable-keep-me-signed-in-kmsi) is disabled for this flow.